# Upload a file in Alfresco using java implementation

Tags: alfresco

Suggest me any basic example for uploading  a file to Alfresco using java. I m new to Alfresco.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example using Python and [cmislib](http://chemistry.apache.org/python/cmislib.html):

```
>>> from cmislib import CmisClient
>>> client = CmisClient('http://cmis.alfresco.com/cmisatom', 'admin', 'admin')
>>> repo = client.defaultRepository
>>> root = repo.rootFolder
>>> someFolder = root.createFolder('someFolder')
>>> someFile = open('test.txt', 'r')
>>> someDoc = someFolder.createDocument('Test Document', contentFile=someFile)
```

And here is an example using Java and [OpenCMIS](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/opencmis.html):

```
// default factory implementation
SessionFactory factory = SessionFactoryImpl.newInstance();
Map<String, String> parameter = new HashMap<String, String>();

// user credentials
parameter.put(SessionParameter.USER, "Otto");
parameter.put(SessionParameter.PASSWORD, "****");

// connection settings
parameter.put(SessionParameter.ATOMPUB_URL, "http://<host>:<port>/cmis/atom");
parameter.put(SessionParameter.BINDING_TYPE, BindingType.ATOMPUB.value());
parameter.put(SessionParameter.REPOSITORY_ID, "myRepository");

// create session
Session session = factory.createSession(parameter);
Folder root = session.getRootFolder();

// properties
// (minimal set: name and object type id)
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
properties.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID, "cmis:folder");
properties.put(PropertyIds.NAME, "a new folder");

// create the folder
Folder parent = root.createFolder(properties);

String name = "myNewDocument.txt";

// properties 
// (minimal set: name and object type id)
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
properties.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID, "cmis:document");
properties.put(PropertyIds.NAME, name);

// content
byte[] content = "Hello World!".getBytes();
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(content);
ContentStream contentStream = new ContentStreamImpl(name, BigInteger.valueOf(content.length), "text/plain", stream);

// create a major version
Document newDoc = parent.createDocument(properties, contentStream, VersioningState.MAJOR);
```

Comment: Hi, Plz dont mind about my english, with the help of web services lib we can connect to alfresco with java. U can find sample code down

Answer (score 2):

Example using Java and OpenCMIS in alfresco :
[Download OpenCMIS jars ( Release 1.1.0 -> Commodity Packages -> Package -> OpenCMIS Client with dependencies )](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/download.html)

Reference [Link](http://34codefactory.blogspot.in/2017/08/upload-file-in-alfresco-using-java-code.html)

```
package com.alfresco;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.api.Document;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.api.Folder;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.api.Session;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.api.SessionFactory;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionFactoryImpl;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.PropertyIds;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.SessionParameter;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.data.ContentStream;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.enums.BindingType;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.enums.VersioningState;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.impl.dataobjects.ContentStreamImpl;


public class AlfrescoFileUpload {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // default factory implementation
    SessionFactory factory = SessionFactoryImpl.newInstance();
    Map<String, String> parameter = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // user credentials
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.USER, <username>);
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.PASSWORD, <password>);

    // connection settings
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.ATOMPUB_URL, "http://127.0.0.1:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom");
    parameter.put(SessionParameter.BINDING_TYPE, BindingType.ATOMPUB.value());

    // create session
    Session session = factory.getRepositories(parameter).get(0).createSession();
    Folder root = session.getRootFolder();

    // properties
    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    properties.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID, "cmis:folder");
    properties.put(PropertyIds.NAME, "MyAlfrescoFolder");

    // create the folder
    Folder parent = root.createFolder(properties);

    String name = "NewTextFile.txt";

    // properties
    Map<String, Object> properties2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    properties2.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID, "cmis:document");
    properties2.put(PropertyIds.NAME, name);

    // content
    byte[] content = "Hello Parth Patel!".getBytes();
    InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(content);
    ContentStream contentStream = new ContentStreamImpl(name, BigInteger.valueOf(content.length), "text/plain", stream);

    // create a major version
    Document newDoc = parent.createDocument(properties2, contentStream, VersioningState.MAJOR);

    System.out.println("DONE.");

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of web services library we can connect to alfresco with java. You can find sample code below

```
WebServiceFactory.setEndpointAddress("url");
WebSererviceFactory.setEndpointAddress("url");
        AuthenticationUtils.startSession(prop.getProperty("user"),prop.getProperty("password"));
        System.out.println(AuthenticationUtils.getTicket());
        ContentServiceSoapBindingStub contService =      WebServiceFactory.getContentService();
```

Create a parent reference:

```
         String path = "/app:company_home/cm:dir" + </pre>

        ParentReference parRef = new ParentReference(STORE, null,path,ASSOC_CONTAINS, "{"+ Constants.NAMESPACE_CONTENT_MODEL + "}"+ fileName); </pre>

       parRef.setPath("/app:company_home/cm:vasanpmsrole");
        String name = fileName;
        ContentFormat contentFormat =
                new ContentFormat(mimeType, "UTF-8");
        NamedValue[] properties = new NamedValue[ {Utils.createNamedValue(Constants.PROP_NAME, fileName)};

        CMLCreate create = new CMLCreate("1",parRef, null, null, null,Constants.TYPE_CONTENT, properties);
        CML cml = new CML();
        cml.setCreate(new CMLCreate[]{create});
        UpdateResult[] result =    WebServiceFactory.getRepositoryService().update(cml) ;
        Reference newContentNode =
                result[0].getDestination();
        Content content = contService.write(
                newContentNode, Constants.PROP_CONTENT,
                b, contentFormat);

         strUuid = newContentNode.getUuid();
```

In this I used following directories:

- axis-1.4.jar
- AlfrescoWebService.jar

Comment: If possible, avoid this approach and use the CMIS approach I posted instead. We no longer actively develop the old Web Services API, which is what you're using in this example. If you want to use Web Services instead of AtomPub, you can change the BindingType constant in my Java example to "parameter.put(SessionParameter.BINDING_TYPE, BindingType.WEBSERVICES.value());" and then set all of the web services end point URLs. There are many examples of this on the web.